# Sequence of nested ideals in a ring with unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Suppose $R$ is a ring with unity, and let there exist infinitely many non-units. I show them with $\{a_0,a_1,\cdots\}$.

I define $aR+J=\{ar+j \mid r \in R ,j \in J\}$

Let $J_0=a_0R \ne R$.

Pick $a_1 \not \in J_0$ and $J_1=a_1R +J_0\ne R$.

Pick $a_2 \not \in J_1$ and $J_2=a_2R +J_1\ne R$.

Let's repeat this procedure: $$J_{n+1}=a_{n+1}R +J_n ;\ a_{n+1} \not \in J_n.$$

Is it possible that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}J_n \ne R$$?

If it is not possible, would you prove it?

If it is possible, I want to add another assumption. Suppose there exist a maximal ideal $I$ in this ring.

Pick $a_0 \not \in I$ and $J_0=a_0R \ne R$. Then the rest is similar:

Pick $a_1 \not \in J_0$ and $J_1=a_1R +J_0\ne R$, and $$J_{n+1}=a_{n+1}R +J_n ;\ a_{n+1} \not \in J_n.$$

Is it possible that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}J_n \ne R$$?

If it is possible, would you give me an example?

Comment: What does $\lim_{n \to \infty} J_n$ mean? Is this a union?

Comment: It means repeating the procedure forever.

Answer (score 1):

The intuitive meaning of 'repeating the procedure forever' would be taking a union of ideals.

The condition you described just guarantees that each ideal is strictly larger than the last (in the sense of containing elements the previous ideal didn't contain). So your question is just whether it's possible to have an infinite, strictly increasing chain of ideals of that form that don't have the whole ring as a union.\

If you have any strictly increasing sequence of ideals, $I_0 ⊂ I_1 ⊂ I_2 ⊂ $ ... , then you can easily produce a strictly increasing sequence in the form you described: just take one non-zero element of $I_0$ as your $a_0$, then for each subsequent $n$ just choose some $a_n$ not in $I_{n-1}$. So your question is just whether it's possible to have an infinite strictly increasing chain of ideals which doesn't have $R$ as its union.

It is easy to say that an infinite strictly increasing chain of ideals is possible- these rings are called non-Noetherian. Suppose we have any Non-Noetherian ring $R$, and some other ring $S$ that isn't the zero ring.
Then there is some infinite ascending chain $I_0 ⊂ I_1 ⊂ I_2 ⊂ $ ... in $R$
Then in the product ring $R×S$,
$I_0×(0) ⊂ I_1×(0) ⊂ I_2×(0) ⊂ $ ...
is a strictly increasing sequence of ideals, and because the union is always going to be some ideal of R multipied by the zero ideal in S, it can't contain the whole of $R×S$. So from this the fact that non-Noetherian rings exist implies that rings like you described exist.